# Easy File Locker Locked My Desktop

Tags: windows-vista

I'm happy with easy file locker, it does as promised.  Last night I decided to lock all my files.    C:users/Barry    Some how my desktop is locked. When I closed  EFL my desktop went black.  Safe mode is still black.  Help  Below are my spec's

10. eMachines ET1161-03
    CPU: Athlon 64 X2 4400+; CPU speed: 2300GHz; Graphics adapter: nVidia GeForce 6150SE; Monitor: No; Hard drive size: 320GB; WorldBench rating: Fair

Comment: Hi, please link to the program in your question, as it's not very well known. I assume it's http://www.xoslab.com/index.html , correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Vista / Windows 7. The files for your desktop are saved in C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop. Also some of your settings are saved in C:\Users\USERNAME\ folder.

You have locked that folder. Hence the issue. Can you unlock the folder somehow?
May be login as builtin-Administrator or any other account with Administrative privileges and unlock.

Or you will need to delete the account (lose all data & settings) and create a new user to login. (Again you will need to login as an admin)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your immediate problem, but will help you prevent a recurrence.

Perhaps you shouldn't use a utility which does this to you. I would consider it a horrendous design flaw.

Windows Vista (maybe?) and 7 (definitely) include BitLocker support (in non-basic editions of the OS, anyway). Use this.

If you're on XP, download and use TrueCrypt; it's free.

http://www.truecrypt.org/

Not only is the encryption bulletproof, you know exactly what you're locking up and what you're not (so you won't ever get into the situation you're in now).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, unfortunately XOSLAB does not  document how "Easy File Locker" actually works.

As far as I can tell from the installer package, it seems to install a special Windows driver which probably intercepts access to files, in order to implement its features like hiding files.

If that is true, you should be able to access your files if you boot from a different medium. Options would be for example:

- boot with a Linux LiveCD, then mount your Windows partition
- boot a Windows LiveCD (e.g. BartPE)
- connect your harddisk to another computer to read it

Then you should be able to see & copy your files.

As to getting rid of Easy Locker, that might be more tricky. You *could* try deleting the files it installs manually (also after booting from a different medium). However, this might wreck your whole Windows install, so only do it after making sure that the recent backup you have (you *do* have a recent backup, don't you?) is complete and OK. If you want to try, you probably need to delete the files `xlkfs.dll` and `xlkfs.dat` from your Windows installation dir.

However, if Easy Locker actually modifies or even encrypts your files to hide them, you might be out of luck...